# How to get data from Parent tag using python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need to extract data from the parent tag, irrespective of the children tags, using Python.
From the code below I need to get "Hi, this is parent tag", without getting "Hi, this is child tag". How can I do that?

```
<html>
    <div>
        "Hi, this is parent tag"
        <span> "Hi, this is child tag" </span>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: use `$(this).parent()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = """
<html>
    <div>
        "Hi, this is parent tag"
        <span> "Hi, this is child tag" </span>
    </div>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt)

for node in soup.findAll('div'):
    print(' '.join(node.findAll(text=True, recursive=False)))
```

OUTPUT:

> "Hi, this is parent tag"

Comment: Hey. Thanks, it works!
Another question though, is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: @SrushtiMehatkar This was the shortest I could relate, you may accept the answer if it helped! cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use lxml package xpath syntax

```
txt = """
<html>
    <div>
        "Hi, this is parent tag"
        <span> "Hi, this is child tag" </span>
    </div>
</html>
"""

from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
tree = fromstring(txt)
print tree.xpath("//div/text()")
```

Good source hint
https://devhints.io/xpath